# Flow screen check if required fields in not empty

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, aura, screen-flow, flowscreen

I have implemented via aura flow  footer and need to check if required fields is not empty. How can i do it?

```
<aura:component access="global" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens">
        
   <aura:attribute name="canPause" type="Boolean" />
   <aura:attribute name="canBack" type="Boolean" />
   <aura:attribute name="canNext" type="Boolean" />
   <aura:attribute name="canFinish" type="Boolean" />
   <aura:attribute name="isEmpty" type="Boolean" />
   <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
        
   <div aura:id="actionButtonBar" class="slds-clearfix slds-p-top_medium">
      <!-- If Previous is available, display to the left -->
      <div class="slds-float_left">
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canBack}">
            <lightning:button aura:id="BACK" label="Previous"
               variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.onButtonPressed}" />
         </aura:if>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-float_right">
         <!-- If Pause, Next, or Finish are available, display to the right -->
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canPause}">
            <lightning:button aura:id="PAUSE" label="Pause"
               variant="neutral" onclick="{!c.onButtonPressed}" />
         </aura:if>
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canNext}">
            <lightning:button aura:id="NEXT" label="Next" 
               variant="brand" onclick="{!c.onButtonPressed}" />
         </aura:if>
         <aura:if isTrue="{!v.canFinish}">
            <lightning:button aura:id="FINISH" label="Done"
               variant="brand" onclick="{!c.onButtonPressed}" />
         </aura:if>
      </div>
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass the flow variables to the Aura footer component for which the validation has to be checked.
2. On Click of any action, verify the value of flow variables and try to display the toast message, if not set a boolean variable on Aura Component and pass it to the flow and display the validation message if the boolean is true.